# Why do rbind() and do.call(rbind, ) return different results?

Tags: r, rbind, do.call

I want to convert a list to a data frame, with the following code:

```
ls<-list(a=c(1:4),b=c(3:6))
do.call("rbind",ls)
```

The result obtained by adding do.call is as shown below. It returns a `data.frame` object as desired.

```
 do.call("rbind",ls)
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
a    1    2    3    4
b    3    4    5    6
```

However if I directly use `rbind`, it returns a list.

**Why does `rbind` behave differently in these two situations?**

```
my.df<-rbind(ls)
str(ls)


 my.df
   a         b        
ls Integer,4 Integer,4

 str(ls)
List of 2
 $ a: int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
 $ b: int [1:4] 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: `do.call("rbind", ls)` returns a matrix, not a data frame.  Same with `rbind(ls)`.

Comment: Because `do.call` extracts the elements out of the list- that's the difference. As if you would do `rbind(ls[[1]], ls[[2]])`

Comment: Thank you @RichardScriven, but the output of `rbind(ls)` is still a list. Actually what I want is to convert a list to a matrix

Comment: No, the output of `rbind(ls)` is a matrix.  It contains list elements.  See `class(rbind(ls))`

Comment: If I use `> str(ls)`, it says it is a list. Though both do.call("rbind", ls) and  rbind(ls) return a matrix, the outcome of them are different

Comment: Thank you @jenesaisquoi, so the difference lies in combinding two list and combinding two elements.

Comment: Thank you so much @DavidArenburg. It helps.

Comment: Because you should read the help page of the function before asking such a question. `?do.call`

Comment: It is common sense to check the help page and search this question in stackoverflow before asking. If I didn't get the solution, I will post it here. @Alex

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`do.call(rbind, ls)` gives you the same output as `Reduce(rbind, ls)`. The later is less efficient, but it serves to show how you are iterating over the objects in `ls` rather than manipulating `ls` (which is a concatenated list of 2 lists) directly.

They both operate by "unlisting" each element of the list, which has class `numeric`. When you `rbind` numeric arguments, the resulting class is a matrix with `typeof` being integer. If you just `rbind` the list, each element of the list is considered a single object. So the returned object is a `matrix` object with 1 row and 2 columns and entries of type `list`. That it has *1* row should make it apparent it's treating the object `ls` as one thing, and not two things. Typing `rbind(ls, ls, ls)` will give 3 rows and 2 columns.